# MS Access - Getting "Enter parameter value" when trying to join 3 tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT students.student_name, grades.grade
FROM students,grades
WHERE students.id = student_enrollment.student_id 
AND student_enrollment.id= grades.student_enrollmet_id
```

I'm getting an "Enter parameter value" box regarding "student_enrollment.student_id"

I have checked multiple times and it is spelled and (pretty sure structured) correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Try with three tables:

```
FROM students, grades, student_enrollment
```

Comment: WOW How'd I miss that :D Thanks